# Multiple knapsack fpt?

Tags: approximation-algorithms, fixed-parameter-tractable

It was an open question whether multiple knapsack is fpt wrt standard
parameter. Since at SODA 2009 Jansen has presented an EPTAS for 
multiple knapsack and an EPTAS implies the existense of an fpt algoritm 
[Cesati and Trevisan 1997] this problem should be solved? I ask, since
the EPTAS has a "parameterized" running time.